# How can I learn more about AWS's RDS Aurora PostgreSQL 9.6.19 upgrade failure?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to upgrade an RDS database cluster engine from Aurora PostgreSQL 9.6.19 before its end of life, I made  copy and tried to upgrade to 9.6.21 and 10.16 but everytime the same problem happens:

> Database cluster is in a state that cannot be upgraded: Postgres cluster is in a state where pg_upgrade can not be completed successfully.

The status of the database is Available so maybe it refers to something else but I don't know what and how to fix it, I've tried looking for answers to no avail.

Has anyone fixed this?

Comment: Have you searched the logs? When you try upgrading the db, you get upgrade related logs. You can search those to have some extra info.

Comment: @Riz I was seeing the logs of the cluster, not the instance. I found them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pg_upgrade_internal`  log file will usually contain details on any failures/errors.

You can take a look on these logs using the command line:

```
aws rds describe-db-log-files --db-instance-identifier my-db-instance
```

Or via console, or RDS API.

For more information take a look on these links: [Upgrading the PostgreSQL DB engine for Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html), [Viewing and listing database log files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Procedural.Viewing.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! I found it on the console but I want to know how to do it via the command line.

The error it's this:
Your installation contains the "unknown" data type in user tables. This
data type is no longer allowed in tables, so this cluster cannot currently
be upgraded. You can remove the problem tables and restart the upgrade.
A list of the problem columns is in the file:
tables_using_unknown.txt

But I don't know how to access that file. I would really appreciate if you could tell me how :)